# Bug with FOSUser Registration ajax

Tags: jquery, symfony, fosuserbundle

Hi i have the weirdest bug : I just wanted to check with an AJAX call that the email wasn't allready taken. What i get is FOS User Login Form instead of just a message saying email taken..

Here are my codes

the jquery part

```
$('body').on('click','.classicinput',  function(){ 


    var emailValue = $('#fos_user_registration_form_email').val();

    //POST ajax
    var DATA = 'email=' + emailValue;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        // Routing.generate = fosjsroutingbundle
        url: Routing.generate('e_veilleur_user_reigster_emailcheck'),
        data: DATA,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){

                $(".ajaxResponse").html(data);
                 //alert(data);

            }
        });    
    return false;

    alert(emailValue); });
```

the controller part which is called by the jquery

```
public function InviteEmailAction()
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $email = $request->request->get('email');


        // si des données ont été envoyé 
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {
            $router = $this->get('router');

            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('EVeilleurUserBundle:User');
            $checkEmail = $repository->findOneByEmail($email);

            // 
            // if($checkEmail)
            // {
            //     $response= new Response("");
            // }
            // else
            // {
            //     $response= new Response("");                    
            // }


           // return $response;
        }
    }
```

First my controller should bug because it has no response ( i commented it ) . It doesn't

For every ajax post call i make (POST localhost/.../web/app_dev.php/user/register/emailcheck), i have an ajax get request in firebug "GET localhost/.../web/app_dev.php/login". 
Any ideas?

Comment: How does your routing look like for the given controller?

Comment: thanks for your comment my route was restricted indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is probably behind the firewall and requires some access rights (roles).

Use the `access_control` in your `security.yml` and specify:

```
access_control:
    ....
    /path-to-email-check-controller: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
    ....
```

Be sure to put it before any similar rule (e.g. `/login`)

Comment: i totally did not think about that. Thanks!